# Primefaces clientValidator message not displayed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, client-side-validation

I tried to use Primefaces

```
<p:clientValidator>
```

along with the

```
<p:message>
```

but without any success. The message is simply not displayed. Here is a snippet of my .xhtml:

```
<h:form id="systemLogTable">
...
<h:panelGroup>
    <p:inputText id="last-input" value="#{lazyLogsDataModel.lastTime}" size="10" disabled="#{lazyLogsDataModel.timeFilteringOption != 2}">
        <p:ajax event="keyup" update="logsTable" />
        <p:clientValidator event="keyup" update="msg"/>
    </p:inputText>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="selectLastType" value="#{lazyLogsDataModel.lastUnit}" disabled="#{lazyLogsDataModel.timeFilteringOption != 2}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Days" itemValue="0"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hours" itemValue="1" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Minutes" itemValue="2" />
        <a4j:ajax event="change" render="systemLogTable" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGroup>
<p:message id="msg" for="last-input"/>
...
</h:form>
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
I also tried with

```
<p:messages autoUpdate="true" />
```

instead of

```
<p:message for="last-input" />
```

and it worked but I prefer a dedicated message instead of global messages.

Comment: You need to include a validator on inputText and selectOneMenu.  Also, did you enable client-side validation by adding the 'primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION' global context-param?

Comment: @codeturner The context-param solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PrimeFaces client-side validation is disabled by default and adding the following global parameter is required to enable it:

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>
 <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```