# Client validation in Primefaces

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to validate (check whether the number is less than 50000) a field on html site, field in inside some form.

```
<p:inputText id="xid" styleClass="span3"value="#{user.xd}" maxlength="5" required="true">
    // the validator does not work
    <f:validateLongRange maximum="50000" minimum="1"/>
    <p:clientValidator event="keyup"/>
</p:inputText>
```

I need to verify it during user's writing data. I also was checking jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form").validate({
            rules: {
                xid: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 5,
                    min: 1,
                    max: 50000
                }
            },
            messages: {
                xid: {
                    required: "This is mandatory. Either generated or  manually entered!",
                    maxlength: "Max length is 5 digits",
                    max: "Max Value is 50000",
                    min: "Min is 1",
                    pattern: "Cannot contain characters nor starting with 0."
                }
            }
        });
});
```

The issue in the solution is the fact, that when JSF is applied the id's of forms are no so simple like "form"- names contains also ":" and JavaScript cannot handle them.

Comment: There are many choices for this question. The 'real time validation' concept does not exist. 'Client side validation' and 'Server side validation' are the proper terms. JSF by its own doesn't have client side validation capabilities, but you can play with the ajax events to send the input to the server each time a user performs a key up event. That's not as fast as the client side validation, but it's perfectly valid. As you need to validate the value on the server side (remember, server side validation is a MUST in the www) I suggest you to try it and let the client for later.

Comment: Maybe you can use an inputmask for this? And what is wrong with the PrimeFaces clientValidator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Forget about adding extra *jQuery* code and just go with the JSF validator along with the PrimeFaces client validator tag. You'll see how the input field turns red for values greater than 50000. I personally tend to use the `change` event instead of `keyUp`, I consider it to be more user friendly:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:comp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/comp"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head />
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:messages autoUpdate="true" />
        <p:inputText value="#{val}" maxlength="5" required="true">
            <f:validateLongRange maximum="50000" minimum="1" />
            <p:clientValidator event="change" />
        </p:inputText>
        <p:commandButton value="Check" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Don't forget to enable the client side validation in your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**See also:**

- [Primefaces clientValidator message not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740225/primefaces-clientvalidator-message-not-displayed)

Comment: Probably that is the solution, I forgot to edit web.xml but why -1 '-(

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I think downvoters have to provide comments  explaining why

Comment: But does this mean that it won't technically be evaluated server-side?

Comment: @Andrew, JSF performs server side validation, Primefaces goes the extra mile adding the client-side piece.